# recyclerview fails to request focus on the last item on 6th position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview for stocking and when user hit "enter" on Qty edittext (the right one),it will add new item and focusing on barcode edittext (the left one) but strangely it only work 90% and sometime in some condition (that i dont know) it fails to set focus to the latest barcode edittext.

**screenshot showing it request focus successfully to latest item:**

[image]

**and the failed one:**

[image]

and i tried debug the data in logcat showing `false` which means it should not focus there

[image]

and this is my script `onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerViewBarcodeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    val contact = mContacts[position]
    Log.d("dfocus", contact.isFocus.toString() + " = " + contact.barcode)

    viewHolder.positionTextWatcher.updatePosition(position)
    viewHolder.barcodeEditText.setText(contact.barcode)


    if (contact.isFocus)
    {
        viewHolder.barcodeEditText.requestFocus()
    }

    contact.isFocus = false

}
```

How i can fix this? I need to make sure it focus on the right place because the cashiers need to be fast without having a look to their phone.

this is how I add new item :

model:

```
fun add(barcode: String, qty: Int): ArrayList<BarcodeList>
    {
        for (i in 0 until barcodeList.count())
        {
            barcodeList[i].isFocus = false
        }

        val contactModel = BarcodeList(barcode, qty)
        contactModel.isFocus = true
        barcodeList.add(contactModel)

        return barcodeList
    }
```

onkeylistener:

```
barcodeList = BarcodeList.add("20", 10)
                adapter = RecyclerViewBarcodeAdapter(mContext, recyclerView, barcodeList)
                val curSize = adapter.itemCount
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(curSize-1)
```

Comment: by default is focus is true right??

Comment: i just edited my question and added my script to add new item

Comment: when do you add the new item ..?? onScrolling of the recyclerView ??

Comment: everytime user hit enter on quantity edittext (the right edittext)

Comment: so you want to request focus..on the last item before the user enters qty right??

Comment: user hit enter on the last qty edittext --> insert new item. in the image above (the failed one), it will add new item when I hit enter on edittext contains number 6.

Comment: i am updating my answer...check and let me know...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165027/discussion-between-kakashi-and-santanu-sur).

Comment: just changed the onKeyListener code..

Comment: update if it doesnot work.. @Kakashi

Comment: did you check using `notifyDataSetChanged()`  instead of `itemInserted`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems the problem is because I try to set focus before edittext ready. so to solve it i put delay before requesting focus in onBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerViewBarcodeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
....
val contact = mContacts[position]
if (contact.isFocus)
    {
        viewHolder.barcodeEditText.postDelayed({
            viewHolder.barcodeEditText.requestFocus()
        }, 300)
    }
....
}
```